# unique random timestamp in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, random, timestamp

I am trying for many hours to do it. I need to create  100.000 rows and timestamp is primary key. thats why it must be unique.

I wrote some code, it can generate 100 random timestamp but if i try it for more than 100 such as 1000 or 10000, i have an error, like that

> ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "position_pkey"
>   SQL state: 23505 Detail: Key ("timestamp")=(2014-03-09
>   04:03:16.843499) already exists.

I dont know how to create 100.000 timestamp unique.

this is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_random(count integer DEFAULT 1)
  RETURNS SETOF timestamp AS
$BODY$
    BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT distinct NOW()::timestamp + '10ms'::interval *RANDOM()*RANDOM()
FROM generate_series(0,count);

            --SELECT (NOW() - '10000000'::INTERVAL * ROUND(RANDOM() * RANDOM()))::timestamp
                    --     FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, count);
        END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 1000;
```

and this is generate_random function that generates double numbers randomly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION generate_random(c integer DEFAULT 1, min double precision DEFAULT 0.0, max double precision DEFAULT 1.0)
  RETURNS SETOF double precision AS
$BODY$
        BEGIN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT min + (max - min) * RANDOM()
                         FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, c);
        END;
    $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE STRICT
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

and I call this function like that in query

```
INSERT INTO "mytable"(
            "timestamp", x, y, z)
    VALUES (generate_random(1000), generate_random(1000, 0, 50), generate_random(1000, 0, 50), generate_random(1000, 0, 50));
```

So, I want to create 100.000 rows that are unique timestamps and some random double numbers (doesnt matter unique or not)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to guarantee a unique timestamp is to add a delay between the inserts. In instead you can use a serial

```
create table mytable (
    s serial primary key,
    ts timestamp,
    x int,
    y int,
    z int
);
insert into mytable (ts, x, y, z) 
select 
    clock_timestamp(),
    500 * RANDOM(),
    500 * RANDOM(),
    500 * RANDOM()
from generate_series(1, 1000)
;
```

Comment: `well distributed` != `random`, but the difference does depend on the OP's requirements.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will try this code, but what about delay in postgresql? I googled and havent find a sample.. i just see some sleep function.. is it good for 100.000 rows?

Comment: @Clodoaldo Neto, I used your code,it seems fine but i want to generate double number between -100 and 100. I dont know it doesnt work. I wrote 100 instead of 500, it stills generates number till 500.. it is weird..?

Answer (score 2):

[There's a function on the PostgreSQL wiki, `pseudo_encrypt`, that will produce pseudo-random values distributed across the 32-bit integer space](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt).

The same approach, of a 1:1 mapping from a sequence using a feistel cypher, could be used for timestamps.

Or you could use a non-repeating iterative pseudo-random number generator.

The main thing is that you must be careful if scaling the result down into a smaller space, as collisions will appear.

Answer (score 0):

The [permuteseq](http://pgxn.org/dist/permuteseq/) extension can be
used to produce intervals containing unique values with a random-looking
distribution.

Here's an example to produce `100000` unique timestamps within
`10000000` (10 million) possible values, based on
multiplying elements from the pseudo-random sequence by `10ms` intervals
added to `now()`.

```
CREATE EXTENSION permuteseq;

CREATE TABLE uniq_tstamp(t timestamp);

INSERT INTO uniq_tstamp
 SELECT now()+range_encrypt_element(elt, 1, 10000000, 1234::bigint) * '10ms'::interval AS t
 FROM  generate_series(1,100000) AS elt;
```

The `1234` constant is an obfuscating key: choose any other `bigint` you want to obtain different series of results.

If we check the result in terms of unicity of values and size of the interval:

```
 SELECT min(t),max(t),count(distinct t) FROM uniq_tstamp ;

            min             |            max             | count  
----------------------------+----------------------------+--------
 2017-02-02 16:00:50.750651 | 2017-02-03 19:47:30.350651 | 100000
(1 row)
```

A peek at the first values:

```
 SELECT * FROM uniq_tstamp limit 10;
             t              
----------------------------
 2017-02-03 14:42:44.420651
 2017-02-03 11:40:37.200651
 2017-02-02 17:28:50.470651
 2017-02-03 00:34:12.060651
 2017-02-03 00:02:16.780651
 2017-02-03 05:53:41.550651
 2017-02-02 21:53:49.900651
 2017-02-03 02:58:37.420651
 2017-02-03 05:25:00.730651
 2017-02-03 09:13:42.110651
```

The randomization applied by `permuteseq` is not crypto-grade, but it's reasonable.